# Cyclical indexing of lists in Python

Tags: python, data-structures

Say I have an array `foo` with e.g. elements `[1, 2, 3]`, and that I want to retrieve elements of `foo` as if `foo` had been "*infinitely concatenated*".

For example `foo[0:2]` would return (like a normal list):

`[1, 2]`

and `foo[0:5]` would return:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

while `foo[7:13]` would return:

```
[2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Are there any data containers in Python or extended modules that already facilitate this type of access? If not, what would be a good/easy way to provide this container?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to implement it yourself. It isn't difficult though:

```
class cyclist(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return list.__getitem__(self, index % len(self))

    def __getslice__(self, start, stop):
        return [self[n] for n in range(start, stop)]


foo = cyclist([1, 2, 3])
print foo[0:2]    # [1, 2]
print foo[7:13]   # [2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
print foo[0:5]    # [1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
```

It's missing some details like taking care of omitted slice parameters, negative numbers in slices, and slice step.

Answer (score 2):

You should be careful when working with sequences which look like lists but behave inherently different.
I would suggest using Pavel Anossov's cool implementation, but providing designated `get_cyclic_item` and
`get_cyclic_slice`, instead of overriding list's `__getitem__` and `__getslice__`.

The user of the class can easily make assumptions about the behavior of the list he's using (expecting an ISA relation, as in "cyclicallist IS A list"), which would lead to bugs/errors.

Here are some examples for cases where using your list can get confusing, if the caller is not aware he's using a `cyclicallist` instead of a regular list...

```
a = cyclicallist([ 0, 1, 2 ])
# appending a value at the end changes an "existing" index
print a[100]
a.append(99)
print a[100]
# deleting a value changes an index preceding it
print a[100]
del a[999]  # currently gives an error: IndexError: list assignment index out of range
print a[100]  # even if no error, what should this print?
# hmm...
del a[100:99999]
```

And of course, the semantic for empty `cyclicallist` is not well-defined...

Comment: I do not know the OP's context but most of those problems seems to be solvable by defining the new data structure as a immutable type, and it can be enough to him/her. Not that you are wrong - I would use your approach too! - but it is interesting that such constraint can solve some problems and, if the OP really needs this behavior, probably the constraint is also valid in the OP's problem.

Comment: @brandizzi, good point. Perhaps `class cyclicaltuple(tuple): ...` is the way to go.

Comment: A tuple would be semantically wrong. A tuple is a record with a fixed and known number of elements. Also you can't call it `cyclist` :) I think it's enough to pronounce `cyclist`s immutable (maybe inherit from `collections.Sequence`).

Comment: I hear you about not being able to call it `cyclist`.  An obvious deal breaker.  But I'm not sure I understand what you mean about the semantics.  I view tuples merely as immutable-lists.

Comment: [This pretty much sums up my view](http://jtauber.com/blog/2006/04/15/python_tuples_are_not_just_constant_lists/).

Answer (score 2):

Even if it will be ridiculously inefficient compared to the modulo based implementation suggested above, I think that using `itertools` could be a fun way to do it…

```
>>> from itertools import islice, cycle
>>> make_cyclic = lambda lst: lambda start, stop: list( islice( cycle( lst ), start, stop ) )
>>> make_cyclic( [ 1, 2, 3 ] )
>>> c(7, 13)
[2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```